# Gesture event interferes with property observer catching property in invalid state

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I use following class to manage list of image slides and track active slide:

```
class Slides
{
    var list: [String] = []
    var activeIndex: Int = 0
    {
        didSet
        {
            if activeIndex < 0
            {
                activeIndex = list.count - 1
            }
            else
            if activeIndex > list.count
            {
                activeIndex = 0
            }
        }
    }

    var active: String
    {
        get
        {
            return list[activeIndex]
        }
    }

    func next() -> Int
    {
        return activeIndex++
    }

    func prev() -> Int
    {
        return activeIndex--
    }
}
```

Functions `prev()` and `next()` give me previous or next slide in circular manner - wrapping to beginning or end of slide list.

I am using `activeIndex` property observer to prevent setting invalid index.

In application I use swipe gestures to show next or previous slide.

```
@IBAction func onSwipeLeft(sender: AnyObject)
{
    slides.next()
    let slide = slides.active
    ...
}

@IBAction func onSwipeRight(sender: AnyObject)
{
    slides.prev()
    let slide = slides.active
    ...
}
```

It works well most of the time, but occasionally swiping back and forth triggers `array index out of range` exception in `active` property getter. That means gesture event breaks in and executes code between setting actual value to `activeIndex` and calling its observer that prevents `activeIndex` storing invalid value.

Question is why is that happening in the first place and what is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your code on this line:

```
if activeIndex > list.count
```

It should be:

```
if activeIndex >= list.count
```

Comment: @dfri if you mean that I assume that list alway has elements even though it looks like it may be empty, I have that part covered.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Or I'll just mention it here: the `myIntVar++` will become deprecated in Swift 3, so as not to break your app in the future, you're probably better of to use `myIntVar = myIntVar + 1`.

Comment: @dfri Thanks, that should not be a big problem :)

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I see. In you example above, I see that your functions `prev()` and `next()` returns an integer that is not used. Perhaps you're aware of this, but make sure to take care _if_ you choose to use this, as `return myIntVar++` will return `myIntVar`:s _current_ value, and only after that increase the value of it. Anyway, just a note about `++` :)

Comment: @dfri Thanks. Original code had that in two lines, but I was trying to optimize code for SO while trying to track concurrency error, and error was still here with changed code... I guess it is time for me to take a break...

Comment: @dfri If you like you can write answer about ++ and prev() and next() , even though it does not cover original issue, you deserve some imaginary Internet points :)

Answer (score 1):

user3608334:s answer above points out the off-by-one mistake leading the runtime exception, but I'll thought I'd add a few points regarding the code that could possibly be valuable.

---

The `++` and `--` operators will be deprecated in Swift 3.

- https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md

Regarding the current use of it, note that the return statement `return activeIndex++` and `return activeIndex--` in `next()` and `prev()` methods, respectively, will return the a copy of the current value of `activeIndex` *prior* to mutation.

```
// ...
activeIndex = 1
return activeIndex++ /* returns 1, activeIndex is set to 2 */
```

Possibly the `next()` and `prev()` functions need not return a value, only mutate `activeIndex`, at least given how you call them in your example.

Finally, note that if a computed property have only a getter, then you can leave out explicitly stating that (and only use one set of braces).

---

Wrapping up the notes from above, we could write your class as:

```
class Slides
{
    var list: [String] = []
    var activeIndex: Int = 0 {
        didSet
        {
            if activeIndex < 0 {
                activeIndex = list.count - 1
            }
            else if activeIndex >= list.count {
                activeIndex = 0
            }
        }
    }

    var active: String {
        return list[activeIndex]
    }

    func next() // -> Int
    {
        activeIndex = activeIndex + 1
        // return activeIndex
    }

    func prev() // -> Int
    {
        activeIndex = activeIndex - 1
        // return activeIndex
    }
}
```

Comment: I just noticed that your `didSet` logic is not the right one. If activeIndex value is out of bounds it should not be set to old value, but should wrap around - if it is `<0` it should become `count-1` and if `>=count` it should become `0` Not important for me, but for future readers...

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Ah I missed that it was supposed to continuously scroll back to beginning if beyond last slide, my bad (thought it was to stop at end/start slide). Will update, thanks!